# How does one set boot priority to cd?

Tags: windows-xp, boot, bios

So today my dad's friend came over and showed us the fact that his laptop was not booting. It would show the acer logo, show a 'windows did not shut down correctly' message and then attempt to boot into XP, give a bluescreen (that disappears before you can read it) then go to the 'windows did not shutdown correctly message'.

So I thought that in order to solve this, I must use an xp install disk and boot the computer from there. [Please read all of this. I did not know which to include or not include, sorry.]

Know once I go to BIOS setup, I do not know how to do this.

## Pheonix TrustedCore (tm) Setup Utilty

<kbd>INFORMATION TAB</kbd>
CPU TYPE: Genuine Intel(R) CPU     T1350
CPU SPEED: 1.86GHz
IDE1 MODEL NAME: Hitachi NTS543225L9A300-(S1)
IDE1 SERIAL NUMBER: I will not post this due to the fact it is a serial number.
ATAPI MODEL NAME: TSSTcorpCD/DVDW TS-L632D-(SS)
SYSTEM BIOS VERSION: V1.23
VGA BIOS VERSION: 5.72.22.43.48
KBC VERSION: 08.26
SERIAL NUMBER: I will not post this due to the fact it is a serial number.
ASSET TAG NUMBER: none
PRODUCT NAME: TravelMate 5610
MANUFACTURER NAME: Acer
UUID: This is an id, so I'm guessing this is sensitive info.

<kbd>MAIN TAB</kbd>
System Time: [17:04:44]
System Date: [09/25/2015]

System Memory: 640KB
Extended Memory: 1002MB
Video Memory: 128MB

Quite Boot: [Enabled]
Power on Display: [Auto]
Network Boot: [Enabled]
F12 Boot Menu: [Disabled]
D2D Recovery: [Enabled]

<kbd>SECURITY TAB</kbd>
Supervisor Password is: Clear
User Password is: Clear
HDD 0 Password     HDD Pasword Frozen

Set Supervisor Password: [Enter]
Set User Password: [Enter]

Password on Boot: [Disabled]

<kbd>BOOT TAB</kbd>
Boot priority order:
1: IDE HDD:  Hitachi HTS543225L9A300-(
2. Ide CDROM: TSSTcorpCD/DVDW TS-L632D-
3. PCI LAN: Realtek Boot Agent
4. USB HDD:
5. USB CDROM:
6. USB FDC:
7. USB KEY:

**_________________________________________________**
Notes: These are all of the options + tabs on the BIOS SETUP UTILITY
So, to sum up my question, how do I change my boot order to boot from the CD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the **boot** tab, Boot priority order:

Choose using arrow keys, `IDE CDROM: TSSTcorpCD/DVDW TS-L632D` and move it to the top in the list. (The keys (`+` or `-`in your case, probably) to move it to top will be listed on right of the same window)

Then move to **Exit** tab (using <kbd>Esc</kbd> and arrow keys) and choose `Save and exit` or `Exit saving settings` and select `yes`.

The machine will reboot. Eject the CD/DVD tray, insert the Windows XP disc adn wait for a message `Press any key to boot from CD...`

 Now hit any key to boot from CD and repair or reinstall XP...

Comment: Very illustrated answer.