# How can one connect to wifi without having to install drivers on XP?

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking, internet

I ran into a problem while attempting to fix my friend's computer. It was stuck in a reboot loop from a virus that prevented booting. So I did the natural and booted from an install disk ([How does one set boot priority to cd?](https://superuser.com/questions/978298/how-to-set-boot-from-cd-on-acer-invillink-signalup/978300#978300)) (Note that this question's answer applies to an computer.)

I just freshly installed WINDOWS XP (it used to run VISTA) and want to start surfing the web right away without installing drivers. This computer was made for VISTA, so I think I might get some trouble for I downgraded from XP.

Is there any workaround to get the internet without the drivers installed? Let me tell that I always get headaches when doing this stuff, so if you can, please leave a link below In the comments where I can install drivers (if possible at all).

TECH SPECS:
Computer Manufacturer: Acer
Model: TravelMate 5610
Designed for: VISTA (32-bit)
Running: XP (32-bit) Service Pack 3

NOTE:
I later answered this question. :(

Comment: It looks like the correct drivers are installed. How are you trying to connect? What goes wrong?

Comment: Sorry, the photo isn't from the laptop

Comment: Then you've given us nothing to go on.

Comment: We have no way to tell which devices have/require which drivers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29553/discussion-between-rookietec9-and-david-schwartz).

Comment: @RookieTEC9, what do you mean by **My virtual xp's connection:** ?

Comment: The connection on my virtualized XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. 
It is impossible for windows to use any signal coming from your built in modem (or whatever piece connects you to the internet) without having drivers installed. Think of it as trying to catch fish without a fishing rod. (I don't recommend you try that.) You can look at your manufacturer's website to download the drivers, (in this case acer.com) but you need a computer WITH drivers to do this.

Once you search for the drivers, download the drivers labeled `MODEM`, and `WIRELESS LAN`. (It may vary by manufacturer)

Once you copy the files to a usb or cd, turn on your laptop, and plug in the usb. Then, open the setup files and complete the installation. Depending on the setup, you may have to reboot your computer.

From there, the computer should identify all open networks. You may have to reboot for the installation to finish.

I suggest that once you are properly connected, you download *FIREFOX* or *CHROME* and install the rest of your drivers. Since you are running XP, Internet Explorer 8 is no longer supported. In fact, I recommend you rush out of XP altogether, but that is just an opinion of mine (and Mirosoft's).